# Question about Tangent Planes:

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, plane-curves, tangent-line

So the surface $S$ is given to be  $z=x\sin(x+y)$ and the point $(2,-2,0)$ is given. When solving for a tangent plane, I got the equation:

$z = 2(x-2) + 2(y+2)$

So the vector-function of a space curve is $r(t) = <a(t),b(t),c(t)>$ on the surface $S$. And it is supposed that $c(t) = a(t)\sin(a(t)+b(t))$ for all real numbers of $t$. $r(0)$ is said to equal $<2,-2,0>$.

How can I prove that $r'(0)$ is PARALLEL to the tangent plane equation found above?

Also, is the tangent line to $C$ at $r(0)$ on the tangent plane? Can this be inferred from some general fact about space curves, tangent lines, and tangent planes?

Comment: I think you mea $c(t) = a(t)\sin(a(t)+b(t))$. You said $r(t)$ instead of $c(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the equation:

$$ c = a \sin(a+b) $$

Everything ($c$, $a$, and $b$) are functions of $t$, but I will just write $a$ instead of $a(t)$, etc...

Now take the $t$-derivative of both sides of the equation (using product and chain rules):

$$ c' = a' \sin(a+b) + a\cos(a+b) \cdot (a'+b') $$

Now we plug in $t=0$, remembering that $a(0) = 2$ and $b(0) = -2$:

$$ c'(0) = 2a'(0) + 2b'(0) $$

The derivative $r'(0)$ is the vector $(a'(0), \, b'(0), \, c'(0))$. By the above equation, $r'(0)$ satisfies the tangent plane equation:
$$ z = 2(x-2) + 2(y+2) = 2x + 2y $$